# cx_freeze copies dll from wrong location

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm using `cx_freeze` to generate an exe for a simple PyQt application with python 3.2 x86 under 64bit Windows.

The problem is that while `cx_freeze` copies all the dependencies perfectly fine together, it for some strange reason doesn't use the `QtCore4.dll` from my python install, but instead does the following:

```
copying D:\Python\Python 3.2 x86\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd -> build\exe.win32-3.2\PyQt4.QtCore.pyd
copying C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\QtCore4.dll (!!) -> build\exe.win32-3.2\QtCore4.dll
```

now that isn't much of a problem if I'm creating the 64bit version (although still not perfect), but clearly a 64bit dll won't work for my 32bit exe. So how do I get `cx_freeze` to stop looking in my system path for dlls and instead let it search in `sys.path` or some other path in my control?

I tried setting the `path` option to `sys.path` explicitly but to no avail.

Comment: Which path related command line options have you tried? Also, have you tried modifying the PATH environment variable in the command line before running the script(`SET PATH=C:\python32...`)?

Comment: @Jesse Just the `path` option for `build_exe`, but that only seems to be important for python files and not the dll. If I remove the `MikTeX` install from the system path, it uses the right dll (yes that's my current workaround), but I'd prefer a solution that didn't involve such a hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least 3 options I can see based on the data provided:

1) You can add the option `bin-path-excludes` to the `build_exe` file with the paths you wish exclude from the process. Specific to your example:

```
bin-path-excludes: ["C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64",] ,
```

2) Rearrange you PATH permanently so that the miktex entry comes later than the QtCore4.dll import you want to use.(this probably has consequences that preclude it from being a viable option)

3) Wrap the call to cx_freeze in a batch(or shell) script and manipulate the PATH in the script before calling the cx_freeze script.

I could not find any examples on the web for this sort of scenario so my research is based on reading the cx_freeze source code. There may very well be a more elegant technique but one was not apparent from neither the documentation nor the source code.

Comment: Yeah I hoped there'd be some kind of way to manipulate the path for binaries to only point to the python directory. I'm now using a script which sets the environment variables correctly - not conventional but at least it should work for everyone.